# Connected component labelling Vs Blob detection Vs Contours

Tags: opencv

Can any body please tell me the basic difference between connected component labelling, blob detection and contours in OpenCv??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, connected components and blobs are synonyms. Contours are the different thing.

A contour is a line that represents a sudden color change in an image.

A connected component is a set of adjacent pixels of the same color.

In relation to OpenCV, it currently doesn't have any component labeling and blob detection (probably, because it's a trivial thing). However, it has a few methods for contour detection.

So do not confuse contours with connected components.

Comment: Meanwhile OpenCV added functions for component labeling and even bloob detection.